# get flag from database and set within authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

Wonder if anyone can help me with this ive set a flag option within my user table wondering how to tie that up in an if statement before redirect?

```
    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        //database connection string
        OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando; OPTION=3;");
        cn.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select * from User where username=? and password=?", cn);
        //Select the username and password from mysql database in login table
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OdbcType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = this.Login1.UserName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OdbcType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@password"].Value = this.Login1.Password;
        //use asp login control to check username and password
        OdbcDataReader dr = default(OdbcDataReader);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {

            string theUserId = Convert.ToString(dr["UserID"]);
            Session.Add("UserID", theUserId);
            e.Authenticated = true;
            string flagoption = Convert.ToString(dr["flag"]);
            if (flagoption = 0) //error
            }
            //add some kind of if statement
            Response.Redirect("Uploadpicture.aspx");
            {
            else
            {

            //if flag is set to 0 redirect to upload picture page:
            Response.Redirect("UserProfileWall.aspx");
            // if flag is set to 1 redirect to to users profilewall:
            // Event Authenticate is true forward to user profile
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: did either of my answers help at all??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the flag you should use a bit instead but this should work

```
int flag =Int32.Parse(dr["flag"]);

if(flag != 1)
Response.Redirect("Uploadpicture.aspx");
else
Response.Redirect("UserProfileWall.aspx");
```

Comment: your flag is an int which equates to an int32 type

Comment: you mean             int flag = Convert.ToInt32(dr["flag"]);

Comment: int32.parse works if I remember correctly but it doesnt matter just treat it as an int and that should work